# Extract part of the request url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{folder}/**")
public void myEndpoint(@PathVariable("folder") String folder, 
                       HttpServletRequest request) {
//...
}
```

I want to extract the `**` as String. The `**` can look as follows - `/path/to/obj`.

I've came up with the following solution:

```
request.getRequestUri().substring(folder + '/');
```

However, the SonarQube yells that building the reqular expression should be avoided with tainted, user-controlled data.

```
refactor this code to not construct the regular expression from tainted user-controlled data
```

Is there a better, more secure way, to write this extraction?

Comment: You could probably use `.indexOf(folder)` which then could be used inside the `.substring()` method

Comment: What SonarQube rule is not compliant with your solution? "yells" is a bit vague, though...

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis `refactor this code to not construct the regular expression from tainted user-controlled data`

Comment: @Forin: The SonarQube rule has a number or ID for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with the following solution:

```
int position = request.getRequestUri().lastIndexOf(folder) + folder.length() + 1);
String myPath = request.getRequestUri().substring(position);
```

I'm calculating the index where my subpath starts. To do that, I'm taking the last index of the root path. It returns me the starting index of the `folder` String. Then I have to add the length of the String and increase by 1 (stands for slash).

Answer (score 0):

How about using another `@PathVariable`?

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{folder}/{suffix}")
public void myEndpoint(
        @PathVariable("folder") String folder, 
        @PathVariable("suffix") String suffix,
        HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    // ...
}
```

This is applicable when there are no more slashes (`/`) present in the request URL.
Otherwise, I am not aware of any other solution. You might want to parse the captured request and validate using [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).

Comment: Yeah, but if suffix contains some path, divied by `/`, to won't work.

Comment: `/**` matches multiple segments, i.e. `/folder/some/other/path`, where as your suggestion only matches two `/folder/path`

Comment: I see the question was edited after my answer.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis I have put the clarification.